# How do I pin widths equally?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am doing a tutorial in a book and it says to do Editor -> Pin -> Widths Equally, however I do not see this option, so It probably means xcode was changed. How do I do this now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you select two different view in your storyboard?

Just like this:

[image: interface builder]

Comment: thanks. for some reason I thought that was something different.